# get_queryset for ListCreateAPIView not being called

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I have a ListCreateAPIView that I'm trying to override get_queryset, but it is never being called. Here is my view:

```
class DeviceView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Threw this and some print statements, but no sign of 
        # the exception or print statement
        raise Exception
        return None
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        responses={
            201: DeviceSerializer(),
        },
        request_body=DeviceSerializer,
    )
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # This code works fine
        ...
    @swagger_auto_schema(responses={200: DeviceSerializer(many=True)})
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # This code DOES get hit and successfully retrieves all the devices
```

Here is the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r"devices/<serialnumber>/abc", views.AbcView.as_view()),
    path(r"devices/<serialnumber>", views.DeviceDetailView.as_view()),
    path(r"devices/", views.DeviceView.as_view()),
    path(r"api-auth/", include("rest_framework.urls", namespace="rest_framework")),
    path(
        r"swagger/",
        schema_view.with_ui("swagger", cache_timeout=0),
        name="schema-swagger-ui",
    ),
    url(
        r"^swagger(?P<format>\.json|\.yaml)$",
        schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0),
        name="schema-json",
    ),
    url(r"^api-token-auth/", obtain_jwt_token),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

Any thoughts on why the `get_queryset` isn't being hit/overridden?

Comment: Seems like you've overridden get method, are you calling get_queryset yourself there?

Comment: I wasn't manually calling it.  I guess I thought that get_queryset would automatically get called and set `self.get_queryset`.  Manually calling it is doing what I want.

Comment: I was also confused by this.  If you override a method and want to use get_queryset you need to call super() in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the django rest framework code

```
class ListAPIView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  GenericAPIView):
    """
    Concrete view for listing a queryset.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

So first, It is better to override the `list` function not the `get`.

```
class ListModelMixin(object):
    """
    List a queryset.
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

So you are probably missing the super call in list or the self.filter_queryset call. These will make sure that the get_queryset is called.

Comment: Thanks!  All the examples I saw just had get_queryset defined and it would automatically be called.  When I manually called it like your example it worked as expected.